# Differential Equations of the first and the second order

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification

***Q.1. a.*** Show that $y=1/x$
is a solution of $y'+y^{2}=0$, but that if $c≠0$ and $c≠1$, then $y=c/x$ is not a solution.

***b.*** Show that $y_1=1$ and $y_2=√x$ are solutions of $yy''+(y')^{2}=0$, but that their sum $y=y_1+y_2$ is not a solution.

***c.*** What do you conclude from the above two statements?

***Proof:***
***a.***
$y=1/x$ ...(1)

Then differentiate w.r.t $x$ of (1) by both sides, we obtain

$y'=-1/x^{2}$ and $y^{2}=1/x^{2}$. So,

$y'+y^{2}=-(1/x^{2})+(1/x^{2})$
$=0. ♦$

My question is now that, should I take any particular value of $c$ other than 0 and 1 to disprove it or is there any other way?

Moreover, part $b$ is also easy to show that but I need help in part $c$. What is the conclusion?

Comments would be helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: c: Non-linear DE do in general not have (affine) linear solution spaces,...

Comment: What are the affine linear spaces? Any definition.

Comment: How about the answer of part $a$ remaining that $y=c/x$ is not a solution when $c≠0$ and $c≠1$.

Comment: Vector (sub-)spaces and planes in them. // Inserting as you did gives the condition $-c+c^2=0$, as a quadratic equation that has only two solutions.

Comment: Thanks sir. I got it. But I am still not satisfied with part $c$.

Comment: Both parts (a) and (b) are demonstrations of how to show that the differential equation (in each case) is non-linear.